# Accepted answer not ranked first

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, self-answer

I came across [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/881/having-problems-with-sharepoint-server-2010-search-not-fast) on SharePoint StackExchange and noticed that the accepted answer was ranked second:

[image: Accepted answer not first]

Refreshing the page will swap it between first and second position randomly as if it just had the same votes as another answer and wasn't marked as accepted.

I've never seen an accepted answer in anything other than first position. The only strange thing I can see about this answer is that it appears to be answered and accepted by the same person that asked the question and that that person's account no longer exists.

Comment: I'd imagine the accepted answer was answered my the question poster. Self accepted answers don't get pinned to the top.

Comment: "your own answer: There is no reputation awarded and the answer does not float to the top of the list. This can be done no earlier than 48 hours after the question is asked." - from [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/213963)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you accept *your own answer* to your question, it does not get automatically bumped to the top of the answers list and is instead sorted like any other answer.

In this case, both the owners of the answer and the question are deleted, so both of the user IDs for those posts are empty. Logically to the system nothing is equal to nothing, so it's treating the answer as being owned by the asker and not sorting it to the top.

Judging from the context of the answer, I would guess that the asker probably *did* post that answer anyways.

Comment: Interesting. So accepting your own solution to your problem somehow invalidates that as having accepted answer status (i.e. top position)? I thought coming back and providing your own solution to your problem was desired behaviour?

Comment: It is desired behavior, @Chris, and it's still the accepted answer. Personally, I'd rather the "accepted" status said nothing about the answer's position in the list of answers, ever.

Comment: I guess the reason for "nameless deleted" users is that those posts were imported from the older Sharepoint site. Otherwise the Display Name string could not be blank.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta One of the things that makes the Stack Exchange model work is that the correct answer is right after the question. Burying the right answer somewhere among the wrong answers is no better than the broken forum Q&A model that Stack Exchange was created to fix.